# Do we need to have different sizes of Button icon(Share image, Delete image on actionbar) in the android app?

Tags: android

I'm uploading an app to google play store. However I have this one doubt before uploading. I'm using the share and camera image from [here](https://icons8.com/web-app/for/all/share).

My question is do i need to have all different sizes for such small images as well? Right now I've just kept my ic_share and ic_screenshot files directly in the drawable folder.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Not sure if "need to", but you can read more about it at [Menu Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html)

Comment: Oh Thanks. I forgot the term "Menu Icons" and hence was not able to find a solution.

Comment: In general, the term is Iconography. There's lots of Design resources on those docs

Comment: Ugh. I found it but I'm still facing troubles putting all menu icons together.
Like how do i put them in one place? like for launcher icon there are like different folders for each size. How do i create same for three menu icons i have? I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: As long as you have a `icon.png`, for example, in each of the `drawable-*` folder, it will get picked up for [different densities](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range).